# How to include JS based on TYPO3 page layout?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am using `page.includeJSFooter` and need to add files when the page layout is set to a certain value.

I have tried using an if like this:

```
page.includeJSFooter {
  file1 = myscript.js
  file1.if.isFalse.field = layout
  file1.if.isFalse.value = 103
  file1.if.isFalse.negate = 1
}
```

I tried a few variations on that but can't get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your condition has some problems:

```
file1.if.isFalse.field = layout
```

you test if the field has no value (equality to boolean false like 0 or empty string)

```
file1.if.isFalse.value = 103
```

`.isFalse` does not compare to any specific `value`

```
file1.if.isFalse.negate = 1
```

`.negate`should occur one level higher and a negation of `.isFalse` would be `.isTrue`

---

what you need is a compare to equality.
That would be as a simple solution something like this:

```
page.includeJSFooter {
    file1 = myscript.js
    file1.if.equals = 103
    file1.if.value.field = layout
}
```

---

if you use the field `backend_layout` you probably also use the field `backend_layout_next_level` which may set values for pages below.
Then your TS would look like:

```
page.includeJSFooter {
    file1 = myscript.js
    file1.if {
        equals {
            data = levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide
            override.field = backend_layout
        }
        value = pagets__speciallayout
    } 
}
```

trying to get the layout from the inheriting field `backend_layout_next_level`, but an explicit given value in the field `backend_layout` has priority.

Comment: I tried your frontend layout example, but it doesn't include the file on any page?

Comment: the if condition in the provided example is not correct, try https://pastebin.com/pq9Xg6se

Comment: I added the fixed conditions of Bernd in my answer below. Although they are untested, those should evaluate correctly now.

Comment: @Franz-Koch you can use `.field` or `.data` for `.value` and for the *condition*. so it is personal preference where to write the constant and where the variable. As I had to fix an error (it is `.if.value`) I just changed one example to have the constant with the `.equals`

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I know that both properties support stdWrap and that it doesn't really matter - my fix was more about you having the `value` property inside the `equals` node, which you have fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

If you using Backend layouts then may below code help you

```
[globalVar = TSFE:page|backend_layout =pagets__seitenleiste]
page.includeJSFooter {
 file1 = myscript.js
}
[end]
```

If you used frontend layout then below code will help you

```
[globalVar = TSFE:page|layout =1]
page.includeJSFooter {
file1 = myscript.js
}
[end]
```

Let me know if this not working for you I'll try to suggest another way!!

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use FLUID for page rendering, you could also add assets from within the page templates, by f.e. using this ViewHelper https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Asset/ScriptViewHelper.html for JavaScript assets.

Personally I think this logic belongs to the template and not into TypoScript, which is why I always do it in my templates. I use a custom ViewHelper though that adds the assets to the pageRenderer the same way TypoScript does, so that all the compression, merging and other logic of the PageRenderer applies to them (unlike the VHS viewHelper which does it's own thing).

If you prefer the TypoScript way, I'd go with the if-condition suggested by Bernd Wilke

edit: unfortunately the if-condition in Bernds examples are not correct, try

```
page.includeJSFooter {
    file1 = myscript.js
    file1.if.value.field = layout
    file1.if.equals = 103
}
```

and

```
page.includeJSFooter {
    file1 = myscript.js
    file1.if {
      value {
        data = levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide
        override.field = backend_layout
      }
      equals = pagets__speciallayout
    } 
}
```

Comment: This time round I'm sticking with typoscript, but next website I may do as you suggest. Thanks.